# Year months as Column and Fetch data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this in SQL Server 2008

```
SalesMonth    SalesPerson       TotalAmount
-----------   -----------       -----------
3              Ram                10000
3              Rajesh             25000
4              Rajesh             8500
6              Ram                12000
6              Anand              7000
11             Ram                6500
```

Results should be .....

```
SalesPerson   Jan  Feb   Mar      Apr     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct    Nov    Dec
Ram            0    0    10000     0      12000    0       0       0       0     6500    0
Rajesh         0    0    25000    8500      0      0       0       0       0      0      0
Anand          0    0     0        0       7000    0       0       0       0      0      0
```

Is it possible to get through sql query. If so, please help me...

Comment: use PIVOT http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'd create temp table with SalesMonths (ID + Name of month) and then joined it with SalesMonth ID and create pivot output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
SELECT SalesPerson, 
ISNULL([1],0) as JAN,
ISNULL([2],0) as FEB,
ISNULL([3],0) as MAR,
ISNULL([4],0) as APR,
ISNULL([5],0) as MAY,
ISNULL([6],0) as JUN,
ISNULL([7],0) as JUL,
ISNULL([8],0) as AUG,
ISNULL([9],0) as SEP,
ISNULL([10],0) as OCT,
ISNULL([11],0) as NOV,
ISNULL([12],0) as DEC

FROM t
PIVOT
(  SUM(TotalAmount)
   FOR SalesMonth IN 
       ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY SalesPerson;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec689/11)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the SQL Server's [PIVOT operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT SalesPerson, [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec]
FROM (
    SELECT MonthName.SalesMonthName, Sales.SalesPerson, Sales.TotalAmount
    FROM Sales 
    INNER JOIN MonthName ON ( MonthName.MonthNumber = Sales.SalesMonth )
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    Sum(TotalAmount)
    FOR SalesMonthName IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])
) AS PivotTable
```

Also, since PIVOT aggregates data, the example above uses the `Sum()` function. (You could just as easily use `Avg()`, or a different aggregation function, based upon your needs.)

Your output will be **NULL** for all elements that do not have values.

NOTE: In the example above, I made an assumption that there is a fictional table (MonthName) that translates month numbers (1, 2,...) to month names (Jan, Feb,...), since your data does not show the 'jump' from month numbers to month names. If you do not want to do this, replace `[Jan], [Feb], ..., [Nov], [Dec]` with `[1], [2], ..., [11], [12]` in the SQL statement above (and, of course, remove the `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   SalesPerson,
    [1] as jan, [2] as feb, [3] as mar, [4] as apr, [5] as may, [6] as jun, [7] as jul
    , [8] as aug,[9] as sept,[10] as oct,[11] as nov,[12] as decm
FROM
     table1
PIVOT
    (
    sum(TotalAmount)
    FOR SalesMonth IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```